# PhP passing a variable through a for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, counter

Can anyone help me understand how to pass a variable through a for loop? I want to print out variable $guess until the number 40 & print out either "you guessed to low" or "you guessed too high"...how do I connect the variable with the counter??

```
$Me=30;
$guess=$i;

for ($i = 0; $i < 40; $i++) {
    if($Me>$guess){
    print "$guess:you guessed too low<br />";
    }elseif($Me<$guess){
    print "$guess: you guessed to high<br />";
    }else{
    print "you guessed my age! i'm 31!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Me=30;

for ($i = 0; $i < 40; $i++) {
$guess=$i; // move it here
    if($Me>$guess){
    print "$guess:you guessed too low<br />";
    }elseif($Me<$guess){
    print "$guess: you guessed to high<br />";
    }else{
    print "you guessed my age! i'm 31!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop replace $i with $guess.

However, the program will print "i'm 31" although $Me=30.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Me=30;
/* actually you don't need to use $guess=$i; for your needs */ 
for($i = 0; $i < 40; $i++) {
    if($i < $Me){
        echo "$i:you guessed too low <br/>";
    }
    else if($i > $Me){
        echo "$i: you guessed to high<br/>";
    }
    else{
        echo "you guessed my age! i'm 31!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$Me=30;

for ($i = 0; $i < 40; ) {
     $guess=$i;
    if($Me>$guess){
        print "$guess:you guessed too low<br />";
    }elseif($Me<$guess){
        print "$guess: you guessed to high<br />";
    }else{
        print "you guessed my age! i'm 31!";
    }
$i++;
}
```